# Java - Extending HashMap - Object vs. generics behaviour

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

I'm writing a simple `HashMap`-based Cache that works as follows:

1. If the requested `key` **is** in cache, return its `value`.
2. If the requested `key` **is not** there, run a method that produces `value` based on `key`, store both, return `value`.

The code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

abstract class Cache<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {  
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            return super.get(key);
        } else {
            V val = getData(key);
            put((K)key, val);    // this is the line I'm discussing below
            return val;
        }
    }

    public abstract V getData(Object key);
}
```

It's pretty straightforward and works well. However, I *hate* the Sun's decision for `get()` to take an `Object` as its argument and not `K`. I've read enough about it to know that it has some rationale behind it (with which I don't agree, but that's another story).

My problem is in the commented line, because it seems that the cast *has* to be unchecked. Due to type erasure, there's no way I can check whether `key` is of type `K` (which is needed for proper `put()` functionality) and the method is, therefore, error prone.

One solution would be to switch from "is a" to "has a" `HashMap` relationship which is much nicer and clean, but then `Cache` can't implement `Map` which would be nice for several reasons. The code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

abstract class Cache<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public V get(K key) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        } else {
            V val = getData(key);
            map.put(key, val);
            return val;
        }
    }

    public abstract V getData(K key);
}
```

Can anyone come up with any other (even hackish) solution, so that I could maintain `Cache` to be a `Map` and still be type safe in the terms of `get(Object key)` and `put(K key, V val)`?

The only thing I can think of is to make another method named i.e. `getValue(Key k)` that would delegate to `get(Object key)`, but then I can't force anyone to use the new method instead of the usual one.

Comment: You can implement `getA` or `myget`  You can't change the behaviour of Map.get() as you can can't force code which uses the interface instead of your class directly to be recompiled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope.  You've found the right solution in switching to a "has-a" relationship.  (Frankly, having the `get` method compute a new value if one doesn't already exist is surprising, violates the `Map` contract, and can lead to extremely weird behavior for a number of other methods.  This was a big part of why Guava moved away from `MapMaker`, which offered almost this exact behavior -- because it was just so [riddled](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/MapMakerMigration#MapMaker_and_ConcurrentMap) with issues.)

That said, what e.g. Guava's `Cache` does is it exposes a `Map<K, V> asMap()` *view*, which is a thing you could do.  That gives you most of the advantages of a `Map` without compromising on type safety.

Comment: It seems the `MapMaker` indeed did what I do :).

I am partially aware of the weird behaviour. The method `V getData(K key)` is `abstract` and therefore is intended to be only specified (implemented) on Cache instantiation. I even tried to make the class `final abstract` (even though I knew 100% that it won't work) or just `final` (with the method overridable by anonymous inner class - doesn't, of course, work either) to ensure nobody will try to subclass this dangerous piece of code with some business logic.

Anyway, thanks a lot, the "has-a" relationship with `asMap()` giving a _view_ it is.

Comment: By the way, I can't believe I missed the Guava's Cache. I won't use it now (when I have my own implementation) out of pride, but if I knew that yesterday... :)

Comment: You...should consider using Guava's `Cache` anyway. It's used in Google production, so it's been heavily tested and optimized, and it's got [lots](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) of handy features.

Comment: Is it really okay to switch to "HAS-A" relationship (for other Java program generally) ?

Comment: @KeenanGebze Has-a (composition) is mostly preferred, yes. Is-a (inheritance) is usually used wrongly, anyway (as was this case here), so it should be only used when really needed and when you're sure it's architecturally justified.

Comment: Perhaps this is another example for [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

Answer (score 0):

definitly the has-a relationship is a correct implementation. the business logic of how the value is generated should be removed out of the cache class.

Comment: That's the fun part about it - there's no logic! The method is `abstract` and therefore should be only specified (implemented, overriden - whichever you like most) on Cache instantiation. I even tried to make the class `final abstract` (even though I knew 100% that it won't work) or just `final` (with the method overridable by anonymous inner class - doesn't, of course, work either) to ensure nobody will try to subclass this dangerous piece of code with some business logic.